# Objective C : having name collision while adding a framework in my app via cocoapod

Tags: objective-c, namespaces, cocoapods, collision

Objective C: I have added a framework in my iOS app via Cocoapod. This framework has few interfaces, file names(.h .m) and xib files with same name as I have used in my app(i.e. name collision). I am able to build my app successfully(i.e. no name collision error) but I am facing runtime issues like framework's xib file (nib) is linking to my app's .h and .m file.
I think app's class name is having priority over frameworks class. 
How should I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way around this. When CocoaPods are used to build a static library, all of the classes and symbols are concatenated into the main binary during the linking process.

This is why Apple recommends that all SDKs and projects use a class prefix of at least 3 characters (like `ABCMyClass`) and Apple reserves all two letter prefixes for themselves. Many people do not follow these rules, and it can cause this exact issue.

The only way for you to move forward is:

- Rename you class, add a prefix (or different prefix)
- Change the Cocoapods dependency via pull request.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I have one follow up question though,  during the linking process while concatenating same symbols into main binary, whose symbols are given preference : app one or the third party framework one.

Comment: @vin I think the app would be the last code added to the binary, but it’s completely random for all practical purposes.